# How can I make rails rails_xss stop escaping my in template Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, escaping

I am working on a Rails 2.3 project with alot of javascript in the templates, and we just installed rails_xss.  However, we're noticing that the raw javascript in the templates is now getting HTML escaped.

Example:  _partial.html.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (true == true)  && (1 == 1) {
    }
</script>
```

is getting rendered as in _partial.html.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (true == true)  &amp;&amp; (1 == 1) {
    }
</script>
```

Whats causing this, and how can we make it render correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the `raw` helper:

```
<%= raw "if (true == true)  && (1 == 1) {" %>
```

or `html_safe`:

```
<%= "if (true == true)  && (1 == 1) {".html_safe %>
```

Comment: So you're saying, convert my javascript, to ruby, so it'll rerender as javascript?   Although technically correct, that seems really roundabout

Comment: i've edited my example above, its really just inserted with script tags in an ERB partial.   I can't paste the full code, but its essentially whats above